# Reverse substring match in jq array

Tags: json, substring, jq, case-insensitive

Let's say I have an array from file `/some/file.json`:

```
[
    "This.FilE",
    "That.file",
    "Another.FIle"
]
```

Then I have a string `x` with value `ThiS.FIle.is.HeRe`, now I wanted to know whether any of the string in the array matched the substring in `x`, case-insensitive (`true`/`false` result). Is there any clever way to do this with `jq` one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `inside` (the reverse operation to `contains`) on strings with unified case (e.g. `ascii_downcase`). `any` will evaluate to `true` if at least one item matches.

```bash
jq --arg x 'ThiS.FIle.is.HeRe' 'any(.[] | ascii_downcase; inside($x | ascii_downcase))'
```

```json
true
```

Comment: This also logs true if it's not in the array?

Comment: @0stone0 No, `any` defaults to `false`. See `jq -n '[] | any'`

Comment: @0stone0 That's correct. IIUC, `true` is the correct answer, as `"This.FilE"` is a (case-insensitive) part of `"ThiS.FIle.is.HeRe"`.

Comment: Ahhh, didn't notices the substring, i'll get some coffee, thanks